# Send tracking to sales cloud from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm sending email to a subset of Synchronized Data Extension and returning the  tracking to Sales Cloud. Apart from data stream how can I do this.
Can data filters be used for sending tracking data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracking data is pushed back to Salesforce automatically via the Connector when preforming a Salesforce Send (as apposed to a User-initiated Send)  The data is pushed to the IndividualEmailResult custom object.

Salesforce Sends can only deploy to Reports or Campaigns in Salesforce or what's called a Salesforce Data Extension.